# How to Check Google Colab Logs?

Tags: logging, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

I am installing a custom module on Google Colab, but I get the following error:

```
.
.
.
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /usr/bin/python3 -u -c '...' Check the logs for full command output.
```

My question is : where are the logs stored in the Colab directories / how to access the logs.?

Answer (score 1):

In the header Go to Runtime > View Runtime Logs.
The logs will open in a side window.
[Screenshot for convenience](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3VlJs.png)